# Getting Unauthorized Access to Twitter Ads API endpoint

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have signed up to Twitter Ads account. My application ID 21157979 has been granted access to Twitter Ads API. I fetched my account id from ads.twitter.com I am trying to hit the below endpoint which does not require any parameters.

**[https://ads-api.twitter.com/9/accounts**](https://ads-api.twitter.com/9/accounts**%C2%A0%C2%A0)

When I am trying to hit this endpoint in POSTMAN, I am getting Unauthorized access. FYI, I tried this with both Bearer Token and OAuth1.0

```
"errors": [ { "code": "UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS", "message": "This request is not properly authenticated" } ], "request": { "params": {
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: What version of Postman are you using? Recommend at least 8.7.0

Comment: @AndyPiper...yes I am using version 8.7.0

Comment: @AndyPiperdo you think my developer account should be whitelisted to access the Ads API, even though twitter team already granted me access for Ads API?

Comment: If you already have access to the Ads API, that's all you should need. The Ads API does not work with a Bearer Token, you will need to use OAuth 1.0A and have a user that has an Ads account.

Comment: After your application is granted access to the Ads API, you will need to either obtain a new OAuth token or regenerate the ones available via the app portal

Comment: @osowskit do you know if twitter ads api does support `Bearer` tokens? doesn't seem to work for the requests that does with the OAuth1 `Authorization` header

Comment: @baryo no. All access is with user tokens. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/making-authenticated-requests